# Whoosh (django haystack) error IndexError: string index out of range

Tags: python, django, django-haystack, whoosh

When I run update_index or rebuild_index on django for django haystack during build it throws this error

```
  File "/home/ubuntu/webapps/djangoenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 624, in resolve
    new_obj = func(obj, *arg_vals)
  File "/home/ubuntu/webapps/djangoenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/markup_deprecated/templatetags/markup.py", line 30, in textile
    return mark_safe(force_text(textile.textile(force_bytes(value), encoding='utf-8', output='utf-8')))
  File "/home/ubuntu/webapps/djangoenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/textile/core.py", line 1360, in textile
    return Textile(html_type=html_type).parse(text)
  File "/home/ubuntu/webapps/djangoenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/textile/core.py", line 250, in parse
    text = self.block(text)
  File "/home/ubuntu/webapps/djangoenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/textile/core.py", line 465, in block
    if ext or not line[0] in whitespace:
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [bug](https://github.com/textile/python-textile/issues/26) in some versions of python-textile. Upgrade to the newest version.

`pip install --upgrade textile`

Comment: you're right it was the version but I had the latest `2.3` had to downgrade to `2.2`